# How to insert data to xml from a database using java?

Tags: java, android

I'm learning by myself android Java (I'm finishing university and what contributes to this project is Java, PHP and MYSql) and have a question. How does it work to insert data from a database into de XML code from my app? Like, in HTML, you can use JS and PHP to insert and alter the value of an element but how is it done in android? I'm thinking I have to get the data from the database, parse it to XML and then asign it to the element I need it to be in, right? Or am I totally wrong?

Comment: Do you mean like the layout XML files? You cannot and should not edit these in anyway. On the other hand you can dynamically add views that the user actually sees on screen.

Comment: By what I see, I might need to use ListViews, right?

Comment: I suggest you use `RecyclerView` instead of `ListView`.

Comment: as a side-note : `Sorry for any inconvenience.` isn't needed at all, everyone here is helping on their own free time and own free will :)

Comment: Thanks  you all, I'll start to learn about the RecyclerView and try to implement it after I understand it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How does it work to insert data from a database into de XML code from my app?

You don't. You can't (or at least shouldn't) edit the XML files directly. On the other hand, you can use the View API to add views dynamically to the UI that the user sees on the screen. In fact, `RecyclerView` is made for just this purpose.

> Like, in HTML, you can use JS and PHP to insert and alter the value of an element but how is it done in android?

Just to clarify what you mean here, JS allows you to add elements to the DOM that is rendered in the browser. It does **not** allow you to edit the original HTML code that is loaded from the server. In the same way, you cannot edit the XML code in your Android app while it is running. Instead, you add Views to the view hierarchy as the app runs.

> I'm thinking I have to get the data from the database, parse it to XML and then asign it to the element I need it to be in, right?

Just to be clear, while your app is running, you don't use XML at all. Instead, you create `View` objects in Java or Kotlin and add them to the view hierarchy. You should start by learning about `RecyclerView` which in most cases will do what you need.